# List of Figures and List of Listings unequal heading margins

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, tocloft

I am currently using the `scrreprt` documentclass for my reports.
With my current template the List of Figures and List of Listings are shown on two subsequent pages. I realized that the heading "List of Figures" and the heading "List of Listings" are not on the same height on the page.

Is there either a way to change the margins for the `\lstlistoflistings` heading or change all the other headings to the same value?

[image: problematic set]

My current source:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{List of Listings}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\listoffigures
\clearpage

\lstlistoflistings
\clearpage                

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Document body
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\pagenumbering{arabic}        % Set numbering back to arabic numbers
\chapter{Image}\label{image}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{images/sys_res.png}
  \caption{System response comparison}
  \label{fig:System-response-comparison}
\end{figure}


\chapter{Listing}\label{listing}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=python, caption=\protect\detokenize{Example python listing}]
class GumnutDecoder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.PC = 0
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome, can  you show us the behaviour with actual code? There could be thousands of ways an incompatible package (you did mention *template*) hacks base functionality to dead.

Comment: `tocloft` i knew it right from the start. Kick it out.

Comment: @Johannes_B I updated my initial post. I just said _template_ because I am using a set of scripts and pandoc to generate LaTeX code from Markdown. This code is then inserted in my template.

Comment: @Johannes_B Oh my god. I don't know how many hours I have wasted over time trying to fix this problem. But for my thesis it itched me just a bit too much to ignore. Is there any other package capable of changing settings like ```secnumdepth```, etc.?

Comment: You don't need any package to change that. By the way, check your regular chapters to see, that the `toc`, `lof`, and `lot` are the ones sticking out.

Comment: Without `tocloft` you can remove the clearpage commands, they aren't needed anymore.

Comment: @Johannes_B Beautiful! If you wish to post your comment as an answer I would gladly accept it!

Comment: I think there is already an answer on site. I'll look for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KOMA-script uses packge `tocbasic` to deal with *lists of stuff*. There are a lot of options to modify the behaviour of those lists.
Unfortunately, package `tocloft` doesn't care, it provides its own redefinitions of the lists for own purposes, mainly to change the appearance and behaviour for the standard classes.
 Since KOMA has everything prepacked and on board to do the same as package `tocloft`, you can omit it. Once tat is done, you can also remove those `\clearpage`s, as by default, each list starts with a new chapter.

`secnumdepth` and `tocdepth` are counters provided by the LaTeX kernel, no need to add any package to change their value.